# salir de la pagina con un botón

Tags: javascript, html5

tengo un problema, y es que tengo enlazadas 3 paginas.html, en la pagina inicial, puedes darle click a un botón y te dirige a la pagina B, y puedes darle click a otro y te dirige a la pagina C, además puedo volver a la pagina inicial con un botón que hay en cada una de las paginas B Y C, pero en la pagina inicial tengo un boton cuyo objetivo es que al darle click se cierre la pagina, y funciona a la perfeccion siempre y cuando no abra las otras paginas, porque cuando me devuelvo de la pagina C o B, no sirve el botón, solo cumple su función cuando no abra otra pagina. el codigo de mi botón es este:

```
<button class="buttonSal" onclick="window.close()">Salir</button>
```

necesito que me funcione aún despues de regrasarme de las paginas secundarias

Answer (score 1):

Eso pasa porque window.close() sólo funciona cuando es una ventana emergente por ejemplo, o cuando es la única pestaña abierta en el navegador.

Dado que los navegadores toman la privacidad en serio, no es posible saber qué pasa fuera de la pestaña en la que se ejecuta tu página (si se ejecuta en varias páginas podrías usar localStorage, pero eso no sirve en páginas de fuera de tu control) por tanto en la página A podrías hacer que redirija a about:blank por ejemplo. Sería así:

```js
function goHome() {
    window.location.href = "about:blank";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="goHome();">Salir de la página</button>
```

Hay múltiples opciones y todas dependen del navegqdor que se use. Por tanto no es fácil encontrar una solución definitiva y duradera en el tiempo. El hecho es que about:blank siempre existió y aparentemente no hay razones que hagan pensar que se eliminará.

En el pasado se usaba window.home() para enviar al visitante a la página por defecto del navegador, pero según la información de https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/home ya explican que está obsoleta y será eliminada si es que no se eliminó ya de tu navegador.

Comment: en que parte de mi codigo lo coloco??